# C# EF6 issue binding Linq result to DataGridView where date column is null

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

All, I'm having an issue with the Linq query below:

```
private void BindDataGrid(string _filter)
{
    using (var context = new Kennels_Data_ModelContainer())
    {
        var grid = context.Pricings
            .Where(x => x.AnimalType.Type == _filter)
            .Select(x=> new {x.PriceStart, x.PriceEnd, x.Price});

        if (grid != null)
        {
            var results = grid.ToList();
            pricingDataGridView.DataSource = results;
            pricingDataGridView.Columns[0].Width = 80;
            pricingDataGridView.Columns[1].Width = 80;
            pricingDataGridView.Columns[2].Width = 57;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and Entity framework 6, with SQL Server 2012.

The query worked fine up until I changed the `PriceEnd` Column in my database to allow it to hold nulls, and I know that at least one row has a null value in it.

This code is held in a Windows Form and is called by the Load method of the form, to bind to `pricingdataGridView`.

The code throws `System.NullReferenceException` and Additional Information is `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

I've looked all over and I can find plenty of references to dealing with `null` in the where clause of the Linq query, but I an find nothing at all relating to handling `null` values in the returned set.

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, has EF model been updated? NullReferenceException might be thrown if in your model `PriceEnd` field remained `decimal`, but should become `decimal?`

LINQ null check, to avoid these records:

```
... context.Pricings.Where(x => x.AnimalType.Type == _filter && x.PriceEnd != null)...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I need the records returned even if the PriceEnd column contains a null value. The problem is in binding the record (even though the field is null) to the DataGridView.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane [DataGridViewCellStyle.NullValue Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.nullvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) maybe? I have not relevant WinForms experience.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response, and I'll accept your answer as being correct as it helped with formatting the null values in the grid correctly. But it turned out that I had moved the code to bind the data to the datagridview to before InitializeComponent() in the constructor. This solved the issue.